# Eclipse (Oxygen 4.7) & egit (4.8) -- is "stash" now called "create patch"?

Tags: eclipse, egit

I can't find "stash" functionality anywhere - I'm running Eclipse (Oxygen 4.7) & egit (4.8).

But I do see Team -> Create Patch...  -- is this the equivalent of "stash"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***Stashes*** submenu can be found in the **right-click menu of a Git repository node** in the *Git Repositories* view only:

[image]

(The *Create Patch...* command creates a [patch file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix)) which can be shared.)